# XCode iO6: UIWebView Returns Black Screen After Returning from Choosing a Photo

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, ios6

Here are the sequence of events which cause my app to return a black screen:

1.) I select a button on my website via the app's UIWebView that allows me to change my profile picture.

2.) The app pulls up the three standard options from the bottom of the screen: "Take Photo or Video", "Choose Existing", "Cancel"

3.) If I choose either of the first two options and then choose or take a photo, my app returns to display a black screen.  The profile picture is not changed.  I also notice that the following message appears in the console window: "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIFileUploadFallbackRootViewController: 0x1c590e60."

The strange part is that this mobile website 'load photo' feature used to work when accessed from my app's UIWebView.  I first noticed this issue after upgrading to iOS6.  Any ideas on what may have changed or what I now need to accommodate from my website or app?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

2/17/13 Update:

HTML Code on mobile website for loading photos:

```
<form class="appnitro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="mysite.php">
<input id="file1" name="file1" class="button_text" type="file" size="50px"/> <br />
<input id="submitpic" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Picture" />
</form>
```

Note: Using jquery mobile.  Also, if Safari is used to access the mobile website, the upload photo feature works fine.  The black screen is only displayed when attempting to use the UIWebView from within the app to upload a new photo.

Comment: You need to post some code if you want advice on this

Comment: Thanks @JSA986, I added the mobile code used.  Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be because the rootViewController is not set.

You probably have a warning: "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

Make sure you have something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

// Override point for customization after app launch 

_window.rootViewController = myViewController;

...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Benoit, for the answer.  However, I have set the rootViewController in my appDelegate.m with the following line of code: 
'self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController]'
Also, it doesn't appear as though my appDelegate's 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' gets called after choosing a photo from my phone and the screen going black.
The only clue, is that I receive the following warning just after selecting 'Choose A File':
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIFileUploadFallbackRootViewController: 0x1d5ea510>.

Comment: @JRoss didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is not supposed to be called after the photo is picked. It is called at launch and setting the window.rootController to your main view controller prevents the issue from happening. It solved it for me and I had the same exact symptoms.

Comment: Thanks @Benoit, that appears to have worked.  However, I needed to create a sign up page at first open, which resulted in me waiting to push my main webView page onto the navController's stack.  Now when I attempt to set the rootViewController, I get the following error: 
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller <ViewController: 0x1ea36240> as a child of view controller:<UINavigationController: 0x1d551620>"
I am guessing I can't do this after I add the navController Subview.  How would you handle this error?

Comment: @JRoss It sounds like you have assigned the wrong VC as window.rootViewController - maybe you need to assign the navController instead. Another way would be to use Apple's graphical tools (Interface Builder, storyboards) as they take care of that automatically.