# XCODE: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIFileUploadFallbackRootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have in my app a UIWebView, and in that web view I navigate to my mobile site where there is a button input with type 'Choose File' for loading a new profile picture.  Each time I try the 'Choose Existing' or 'Take Photo' options from the resulting pull-up iPhone menu, I receive the following error when my View Controller disappears to allow me to choose a photo:

**"Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIFileUploadFallbackRootViewController: 0x20d65940"**

After an image is chosen, the app just returns a black screen...

When I perform the same operation in Safari, the 'Choose File' function works perfectly fine.

**Notes**:

1.) I am using a UINavigationController within my app (i.e. popping and pushing views).

2.) HTML Code on mobile website for loading photos:

```
<form class="appnitro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="mysite.php">
<input id="file1" name="file1" class="button_text" type="file" size="50px"/> <br />
<input id="submitpic" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Picture"     />
```

*Using jquery mobile.*

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: I don't know about jquery. In normal objective c I was getting this error when I was setting [button addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatePics:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents]; so change it to specific one [button addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatePics:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Well, I don't actually have an objective-C method, @PushpakNarasimhan, for navigating to the phone's picture library.  The jquery code - activated when a user attempts to change their profile pic from within my UIWebView - somehow triggers my app to prompt the user to select an image from the phone.  After selecting an image, the app returns with a completely black screen...  The error mentioned above occurs after choosing one of the two picture options ('Choose Existing' or 'Take Photo').

Comment: Your window's rootViewController is not set.

[See this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16548036/199516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window's rootViewController is not set.

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16548036/199516

Answer (score 2):

This problem generally occurs when i push two view controllers simultaneously with animation.

Comment: So, I am not pushing any view controllers in my viewController code.  I am guessing the UIWebView must be attempting to push a new viewController when the user selects to choose/take a picture?  How can I make this a smooth transition for the mobile website picture selection and returning to the original viewController, @Muhammad?